# Using distance functions to delete specific elements of array lists in GUI application

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I know I have to use the two distance functions :

```
    if (point1 != null && point2 != null && point3 != null)
        page.drawString (String.valueOf(point1.x*(point2.y-
point3.y)+point2.x*(point3.y-point1.y)+point3.x*(point1.y-point2.y)), 5, 
15);
```

And:

```
    private int distance(Point p1, Point p2) 
    {
        return (int)Math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-
p2.y));
    }
```

To compute if my mouse if over these arraylists, I've tried many different ways and have gotten as close as to being able to remove the first index of the array by a click, and then the second index by the second click, but I can't seem to find the way to erasing ones specifically chosen by the mouse.  I added this:

```
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (mode == true)
        {
            nodeList.add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
        if (mode == false)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<edgeList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (point1 != null && point2 != null && point3 != null)
                {
                    dist = (point1.x*(point2.y-point3.y)+point2.x*(point3.y-
point1.y)+point3.x*(point1.y-point2.y));
                } 
                if (dist <= 1000 && dist >= -1000)
                {
                    nodeList.remove(i);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }              
    }
```

But it still didn't work, here's my full code that I keep trying to play with, any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Graph
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Directed Graph");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add (new GraphPanel());
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphPanel extends JPanel
{
private final int SIZE = 10;  // radius of each node
private double alpha;
private JButton print, create, delete;
private JLabel output;
boolean mode = true;

String str = new String("Mode Chosen is : ");
String str1 = new String("Mode Chosen Is : create" );
String str2 = new String("Mode Chosen Is : delete" );

int mode1 = 0;

private Point point1 = null, point2 = null, point3 = null;

private ArrayList<Point> nodeList;   // Graph nodes
private ArrayList<Edge> edgeList;    // Graph edges

private int[][] a = new int[100][100];  // Graph adjacency matrix

public GraphPanel()
{
    nodeList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    GraphListener listener = new GraphListener();
    addMouseListener (listener);
    addMouseMotionListener (listener);

    create = new JButton("Create");
    delete = new JButton("Delete");
    JButton print = new JButton("Print adjacency matrix");
    print.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
    create.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
    delete.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

    setBackground (Color.black);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(400, 300));
    add(print);
    add(delete);
    add(create);
}

//  Draws the graph
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);

    // Draws the edge that is being dragged
    page.setColor (Color.green);

    if (mode1 == 0)
    {
        page.drawString(str, 150, 50);
    }
    if (mode1 == 1)
    {
        page.drawString(str1, 150, 50);
    }
    if (mode1 == 2)
    {
        page.drawString(str2, 150, 50);
    }
    if (point1 != null && point2 != null) {
        page.drawLine (point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y);
        page.fillOval (point2.x-3, point2.y-3, 6, 6);
    }
    // Draws the nodes      
    for (int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++) {
        page.setColor (Color.green);
        page.fillOval (nodeList.get(i).x-SIZE, nodeList.get(i).y-SIZE, 
SIZE*2, SIZE*2);
        page.setColor (Color.black);
        page.drawString (String.valueOf(i), nodeList.get(i).x-SIZE/2, 
nodeList.get(i).y+SIZE/2);
    }
    // Draws the edges
    for (int i=0; i<edgeList.size(); i++) {
        page.setColor (Color.green);
        page.drawLine (edgeList.get(i).a.x, 
edgeList.get(i).a.y,edgeList.get(i).b.x, edgeList.get(i).b.y);
        //page.fillOval (edgeList.get(i).b.x-3, edgeList.get(i).b.y-3, 6, 
6);   

        alpha = Math.atan((double)(edgeList.get(i).b.y-
edgeList.get(i).a.y)/(edgeList.get(i).b.x-edgeList.get(i).a.x));
        if (edgeList.get(i).a.x > edgeList.get(i).b.x) 
        {
            alpha = alpha + Math.PI;
        }
        if (edgeList.get(i).a.x < edgeList.get(i).b.x && edgeList.get(i).a.y 
> edgeList.get(i).b.y)
        {
            alpha = alpha + 2*Math.PI;
        }
        arrow(page,edgeList.get(i).b.x,edgeList.get(i).b.y,0,1.57-alpha);
    }

    if (point1 != null && point2 != null && point3 != null)
        page.drawString (String.valueOf(point1.x*(point2.y-
point3.y)+point2.x*(point3.y-point1.y)+point3.x*(point1.y-point2.y)), 5, 
15);
}

// arrow method to call when making an arrow
private void arrow(Graphics page, int x, int y, int len, double alpha)
{
    page.setColor (Color.green);
    int x1 = x+(int)(len*Math.sin(alpha));
    int y1 = y+(int)(len*Math.cos(alpha));
    page.drawLine (x, y, x1, y1);
    page.drawLine (x1, y1, x1+(int)(20*Math.sin(alpha+2.5)), y1+(int)
(20*Math.cos(alpha+2.5)));
    page.drawLine (x1, y1, x1+(int)(20*Math.sin(alpha+3.7)), y1+(int)
(20*Math.cos(alpha+3.7)));
}

//  The listener for mouse events.
private class GraphListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (mode == true)
        {
            nodeList.add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
        if (mode == !true)
        {
            nodeList.clear();
            edgeList.clear();
            repaint();   
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (mode == true)
        {
            point1 = event.getPoint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (mode == true)
        {
            point2 = event.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (mode == true)
        {
            point2 = event.getPoint();
            if (point1.x != point2.x && point1.y != point2.y)
            {
                edgeList.add(new Edge(point1,point2));
                repaint();
            }
        }

    }

    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent event) 
    {            
        point3 = event.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
    //  Empty definitions for unused event methods.
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent event) {}
}
// Represents the graph edges
private class Edge {
    Point a, b;

    public Edge(Point a, Point b) 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {

        if (event.getSource()== create)
        {
            mode = true;
            mode1 = 1;
        }
        if (event.getSource()==delete)
        {
            mode = !true; 
            mode1 = 2;
            // edgeList.clear();
            // nodeList.clear();
            // repaint();                
        }

        // Initializes graph adjacency matrix
        for (int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++)
            for (int j=0; j<nodeList.size(); j++) a[i][j]=0;

        // Includes the edges in the graph adjacency matrix
        for (int i=0; i<edgeList.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<nodeList.size(); j++)
                if (distance(nodeList.get(j),edgeList.get(i).a)<=SIZE+3)
                    for (int k=0; k<nodeList.size(); k++)
                        if (distance(nodeList.get(k),edgeList.get(i).b)
<=SIZE+3) 
                        {
                            System.out.println(j+"->"+k);
                            a[j][k]=1;
                        }
        }
        if (event.getSource()==print)
        {

            // Prints the graph adjacency matrix
            for (int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<nodeList.size(); j++)
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]+"\t");
                System.out.println();
            }  
        }
    }
    // Euclidean distance function      
    private int distance(Point p1, Point p2) 
    {
        return (int)Math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-
p2.y));
    }

}
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think that you may have deleted another similar question, asking about having nodes capture mouse clicks. If so, then again I re-iterate my previous comment that you should use a collection of Shape type, such as Ellipse2D, Rectangle2D and Polygon, since use of these would allow for use of `.contains(Point p)` and likely eliminate the need to do any distance calculations.

Comment: Yeah I did end up deleting it because I got a flag for duplicate posts, I remembered what you said but I believe I'm supposed to use the distance functions

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, do you have any ideas?